# Wrong Month in Joda DateTime

Tags: datetime

When I run the following code (Java):

```
DateTimeFormatter d_t = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/m/yyyy h:mm:ss aa");
String date = "27/3/2015 2:47:08 AM";
DateTime result = DateTime.parse(date, d_t);
```

I always get the result as: 2015-01-27T02:47:08.000+02:00

As you can see the month and the hours are incorrect.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Month of year is written with a capital `M` as well as hour of day `H`.

Try

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/M/yyyy H:mm:ss aa");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but unfortunately I got:                                              Cannot parse "27/3/2015 2:47:08 AM": Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition

Comment: That's a different issue, see other questions here, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162702/cannot-parse-datetime-illegal-instant-due-to-time-zone-offset-transition-euro

Comment: But this date is a valid date

Comment: I can execute the code on my machine and it works perfectly. If you follow the link above you'll get some more details for your error and a solution, try: ```DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/M/yyyy H:mm:ss aa").parseLocalDateTime("27/3/2015 2:47:08 AM");```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "27/3/2015 2:47:08 AM" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d/M/uuuu h:m:s a" , Locale.US ) 
)
```

> 2015-03-27T02:47:08

## java.time

Your input string seems especially odd. The hour does not have a padding zero but the second does? Strange, but it *can* be parsed using the modern *java.time* classes.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You were inappropriately trying to store a date-time value lacking any offset or time zone information into a data type wielding a time zone.Parse your input string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) since we have no indication of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

```
String input = "27/3/2015 2:47:08 AM";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d/M/uuuu h:m:s a" , Locale.US );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( input + " = " + ldt );
```

> 27/3/2015 2:47:08 AM = 2015-03-27T02:47:08

Be aware that a `LocalDateTime` is *not* a point on the timeline. It represents only a set of possible moments over a range of about 26-27 hours. It has no real meaning until you place the value in context, either applying an offset to get a `OffsetDateTime` or a full time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).